# Test exception in CodeIgniter using PHPUnit/CIUnit

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, phpunit

I have a method in the person_model.php:

```
public function getInfo()
{
    $result = array();

    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch(Exception $exception)
    {
        log_message('error', $exception->getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        return $result;
    }

}
```

and how can I test the exception and make sure that log_message() method will be called when exception was caught ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done very easily, mostly because there isn't a way to mock the call to log_message. From the code above however, you may be able to test what the return value is or might change to if the exception is thrown. For example, let's say that if an exception is thrown, and we can be sure that only in that case will the returned value be an empty array. For this example, we simply test that the count of the return is 0.